# 'version' cannot be a child of the 'Transformation' element

Tags: c#, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I am using XslCompiledTransform.Load and everytime I get the error message:

```
 'version' cannot be a child  of the 'Transformation' element
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<Transformation><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"><xsl:output 
method="xml" /><xsl:template match="node() | @*"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates 
select="@* | node()" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template><xsl:template match="testlist"><xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="test"><xsl:sort select="requestor/code" /></xsl:apply-   
templates></xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet></Transformation>
```

If I remove the version i get the error: **Missing mandatory attribute 'version'**
Do I get the error because I am using the stylesheet inside the Tag 'Transformation'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "Yes". You do get the error because you have but the `xsl:stylesheet` element inside a `Transformation` element

```
<Transformation>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

`xsl:stylesheet` needs to be the root element, so `Transformation` needs to be removed.

Having said that, perhaps you meant to do this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" 
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <Transformation>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </Transformation>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="testlist">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="test">
            <xsl:sort select="requestor/code"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```